# Least reasonable regularity on Riemannian metric tensor to define a metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

We assume that $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $m$, and we assume that $g$ is a smooth Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$.

If $M$ is moreover path-connected, then $g$ induces a metric (in the sense of metric spaces) on $M$. The distance between two points $a, b \in M$ is the infimum of the lengths of smooth curves in $M$ connecting $a$ and $b$. The length of a smooth curve $c : [0,1] \rightarrow M$ is the integral

$$ L(c) = \int_0^1 g( \dot c(t), \dot c(t) ) \; dt.$$

The latter expression makes sense if the Riemannian metric $g$ is not smooth but merely continuous. The raises the following **question:** how low can the regularity of a smooth curve be so that we still have a well-defined metric in terms of path lengths?

For example, in many applications you assume the Riemannian metric to have merely measurable coefficients. This suffices to define the $L^2$ norms on vector fields. The question is whether you still have a distance function in that case.

Comment: Since the expression for $L(c)$ involves the derivative of $c$, how does it make sense if $c$ is only continuous but not differentiable?  It could even be nowhere differentiable.  "Almost everywhere differentiable" is plausible but not correct (see the Cantor staircase function).  I suspect the condition you are really looking for is "absolutely continuous".

Comment: Wait - are you talking about the regularity of the curve $c$ or the metric $g$?  It seems you are switching back and forth.

Comment: Consider the following example: your metric is standard on the plane, but along one line it is twice smaller. Note that $L^2$-norm on the vector fields is the same as in the standard plane, but you can make a shortcut using the spacial line --- depending on the application you have in mind, try to tell what would be right choice of the induced metric in this case?

Comment: Although tangentially relevant, you might be interested to know that there is a way to define a distance for metrics with very low regularity which doesn't require being able to compute the length of curves : $d_g(x,y)=\sup\{|f(y)-f(x)|,\,f:M\xrightarrow{C^1}\mathbb{R},\, |\nabla f|^2_g\leq 1\}$. This in particular makes sense for measurable metrics. However, it won't see the pathology Anton built.

Comment: @NateEldrege: right, that was just an annoying typo. I corrected it.

Comment: @shuhalo: you still didn't correct the part that reads "how low can the regularity of a smooth curve be so that we still have a well-defined metric in terms of path lengths".